# Paytm Payment gateway integration

Tags: integration, paytm

I have developer account on paytm website,and i want to integrate paytm Payment gateway, how can i configure a callback url to which a asynchronous response will be sent when a customer has made a payment. In this asynchronous response we can get those payment related info.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure the callback url for asynchronous response via paytm dashboard.
Please follow the below steps to configure the callback url.

1. Login to https://dashboard.paytm.com/
2. Click on **Developer Settings** in Left menu.
3. Go to **API Keys** section.
4. Configure "Payment notification url" under **CONFIGURE WEBHOOK URL** section.

Comment: ,I can't see CONFIGURE WEBHOOK URL section in API Key section.is that necessary to activate developer account because my account not activated?

Comment: In case your account not activated, please raise it to paytm via developer support

Comment: This doesn't work. No callbacks are made. Their documentation says, we have to get in touch with their support team to set up the webhooks. This doesn't make any sense. We should be able to create webhooks from the dashboard itself like stripe have it on their dashboard, hassle free